# An error occurred while creating development build in xcode 9 beta

Tags: ios, xcode9-beta

xcode beta 9 unable to create development build.As soon as i switch from app URL entry ,xcode throwing an error occurred popup.

What would be the problem here?

Attached image below.

[image]

Comment: You need to do discard changes if you are not use the git. File > Source Control > Commit (⌥⌘C), on the left pane select the files you want to reset, right click on selection and click Discard Changes in the context menu.

Comment: i am not using git and getting error while creating development build from export option of the xcode organizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution.Previous screen **Development distribution options** popup xcode asking for **App thinning option**, I have selected **none** it works. switching between Appthinnig and device varients fixed my problem.